# Detecting same tags pattern in web page using jsoup java

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I am writing a code for detecting matching tags patterns in web page. Here is the example.

```
<body>
 <table width="200" border="1">
   <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Place</td>
     <td>Animal</td>
   </tr>
   <p>hello World</p>
   <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>New york</td>
    <td>Lion</td>
   </tr>
   <b>Code Works</b>
   <tr>
    <td>George</td>
    <td>Sydney</td>
    <td>Tiger</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tina</td>
    <td>Delhi</td>
    <td>Cat</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td> </td> 
     <td>
<a href="/cgi-bin/site_searcher.cgi?START=20&amp;SEARCHTERM=asia&amp;SID=&amp;SEARCH=1&amp;BOOLEAN=&amp;CAT=">1</a>
<a href="/cgi-bin/site_searcher.cgi?START=20&amp;SEARCHTERM=asia&amp;SID=&amp;SEARCH=1&amp;BOOLEAN=&amp;CAT=">2</a>             
<a href="/cgi-bin/site_searcher.cgi?START=40&amp;SEARCHTERM=asia&amp;SID=&amp;SEARCH=1&amp;BOOLEAN=&amp;CAT=">3</a> 
<a href="/cgi-bin/site_searcher.cgi?START=60&amp;SEARCHTERM=asia&amp;SID=&amp;SEARCH=1&amp;BOOLEAN=&amp;CAT=">4</a> 
<a href="/cgi-bin/site_searcher.cgi?START=80&amp;SEARCHTERM=asia&amp;SID=&amp;SEARCH=1&amp;BOOLEAN=&amp;CAT=">5</a>  
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

For above Tag pattern, I need to find the tags which are occurring repeatedly. And to discard those that are not in the pattern like tags **b** and **p**. For first table tags tr and td are occurring . For 2nd table 'a' tag is repeated.
This is what I have done till now:

1. Parsed to DOM tree using Jsoup.
2. Then used node visitor class to traverse the tree. Using head and tail methods, I can enter and exit tags.

But I am confused about how to proceed further.
Note: The tags pattern are not fixed.Tag pattern will vary depending on web page structure. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: @saka1029 For above example the tr tags including td tags of first table. And for 2nd table 'a' tags

Comment: @saka1029 body includes only 2 tables. And remaining elements are nested accordingly.

Comment: Please, share your code.

Comment: Can you clarify what are "*tags which are occurring repeatedly*"? With the html code in your POST can precise what a repeatedly occurring tag is?

Comment: @swapnilgandhi See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35336670/363573

Answer (score 1):

> *But I am confused about how to proceed further.*

Your confusion is propagating and reach us too. However, I'll try to give you an hint.

You can count the tags in your HTML code. If a tag count reaches a certain threshold, you can consider this tag as "repeatedly occuring".

```
// Load document
String html = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// Count tags
String tagsSelector = "*";
Map<Element, Integer> tagsCountByType = new Hashmap<>();
for(Element e : doc.select("*")) {
    Integer count = tagsCountByType.get(e);
    if (count == null) {
        tagsCountByType.put(e, new Integer(1));
    } else {
        tagsCountByType.put(e, new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
    }
}

// Find tag with a count greater than a given threshold
// ...
```

I didn't test the code. Just take it as an idea, some sort of inspiration.

Another idea, you can narrow down the `tagsSelector`. For example:

```
// All elements (tags) under any table directly under body.
String tagsSelector = "body > table *";
```